# C# program to call existing web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How can I call / use web API that supports SOAP and REST? I want to write a program in C# that will use this web API. I didn't get much information on the internet. So far, I have created C# project and added the web service reference (WSDL) to my program. Now how can I use the web API. How to send request or receive response? Can you please refer me some good tutorials ?

Answer (score 2):

The [HttpClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a good starting point. Also there is the [EasyHttp library](https://github.com/hhariri/EasyHttp).

- Code sample HttpClient: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Introduction-to-HttpClient-4a2d9cee
- Introduction to EasyHttp: http://devlicio.us/blogs/hadi_hariri/archive/2011/01/16/easyhttp.aspx

Comment: How can I connect this HTTPClient to an existing web API?

Comment: You're going to have to read the documentation and samples. E.g. http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2012/02/28/consuming-webapi-endpoints-in-your-application.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Adding web service reference creates client classes that can be used to communicate with web service. All created classes will be in new namespace, You have to look for client proxy class (full name depends on WebService name). Create instance of this class. Calling its methods will call WebService. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) you can read about using Web Services in C#